# Mysql installation for alpine linux in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I have still problem with mysql installation on alpine in docker.

I need also openjdk:8u201-jdk-alpine3.9.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8u201-jdk-alpine3.9
RUN apk update && \
    apk add mysql mysql-client && \
    rm -f /var/cache/apk/* && \
    addgroup mysql mysql && \
    mkdir run/mysqld && \
    touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock && \
    touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid && \
    chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock && \
    chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid && \
    chmod -R 644 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock && \
    apk add openrc --no-cache
```

But, in container:
- there is no mysql service (only mariadb, but it is probably standard situation for alpine)
- there is no any my.cnf file in /etc/mysql directory

When I tried `mysql` command, I got error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

When I tried `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root` command, I got error:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)
```

That same for localhost.

Comment: Nothing you've shown starts a MySQL server.  You'd almost always run it in a separate container.

Comment: I tried start MySQL server by log on to the container and start mysql service. But does not it exist. I would like start and run command in docker-compose, but how? Probably I don't understand sth very important to run mysql.

Comment: You should add a separate MySQL container to your `docker-compose.yml` file.  The Docker documentation includes a [Django and PostgreSQL sample application](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) which should be a reasonable enough starting point.

Comment: I did it, and it is works perfectly. But generally I need to execute some sql scripts, which are only in java app container. That's why I would like to add mysql to this one container and execute scripts from entrypoint in docker-compose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all - why do you want to install mysql-server on that specific image?
I would suggest using 2 separate containers - one for the mysql database and one for the application you are developing using that openjdk image.

You can simply use this gist https://gist.github.com/karlisabele/d0bebe3d27fc44a57d1db9a9abdff45a
to create a setup where your Java application can connect to mysql database using `database` (the service name) as hostname for mysql server.

See https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql for additional configurations on mysql image (you should define MYSQL user, password, db name etc...)

---

**UPDATE**

I updated the gist and added the environment variables necessary for the mysql to work... Replace the qwerty values with your own and you should be able to access the database from your Java application via database:3306 using the username and password provided in the environment variables

The volumes definition at the end of the file tells docker daemon that we want to create a persistent volume somewhere in the host file system and use `mysql` as an alias. So that when we define the database service volumes we can simply use the mysql:/var/lib/mysql and it will actually mount an obscure folder that docker created on your filesystem. This will allow the mysql database to have persistent state everytime you start the service (because it will mount the data from your host machine) and you don't have to worry about the actual location of the volume

You can see all volumes by running `docker volumes ls`

Comment: Generally I need execute some sql scripts from Java app in mysql database (create table etc.). When I added database section, I try execute in docker-compose, java app section: "mysql -h docker_machine -P 3306 -u root < some.sql" - I got error about "Host ip_number is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server". Thank you fro example in github. In mysql volumes I should add mysql properties for database (user, pas, etc.)?

Comment: @profiler updated the answer with additional explanation as well as added example environment configuration to the gist

Comment: Thank you so much! But - when I use volume, f.e. I have the repository in gitlab. And I will use only docker image in another server (after properly build in gitlab), there are missing information about volumes. And I can't execute the scripts.

Comment: Oh... I just realised you want to directly execute mysql command from your Java application... In that case you will also need to create a custom image, but all you need to install is the mysql-client

I updated the gist again.
You can test it by simply running `docker-compose up -d` then `docker-compose exec app sh` and then `mysql -h database -u qwerty -pqwerty` and you should be connected to mysql server. So from now on your application should be able to connect to the database

Comment: It very much depends on how you intend to use it on the production server, but in any case, you can use the same docker-compose.yml file (you just need to define port mapping as well) and it should work the same as locally
More about volumes: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference
Morea bout port mapping: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports

Comment: @Karlis perfect! And now, can I run "mysql -h dabatase...." in docker-compose in java app section? I added for this entrypoint: -"mysql -h name_database_cointainer etc.". But without success.

Comment: @profiler Did you try testing the connection with the commands I provided? Just to be sure, I tested with that gist without making any changes and it worked fine for me.
Maybe you're doing it from the Java application and there might be something specific going on there.
Make sure that your are using the service name for database as the host... (service name in the gist is database)

Comment: Yes, it is working. But I am thinking, it is there is possibility for automatic process. I mean, one command docker-compose up, and containers up with database initialization.

Comment: That is how it works. 
With this docker-compose set-up you will have 2 containers - one for the database and one for your application. The commands I provided are just to test the connection. All you need is to run docker-compose up -d and it will start the necessary services and the database gets initialised with the credentials you provide through environment variables.
If you wish to have this set up in production environment, you can map your application service (`app` in the example) ports to the host ports and the requests going to your servers ports will be forwarded to your app

Comment: Yes, but how can I execute sql scripts? Can I send it to docker-compose up -d command? Or can I provide that command in docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: And you want to execute the scripts as part of the entrypoint of your app service? Then you should first define `depends_on` for the app service so that it would first start your database service and only then the app, but also I would suggest using some sort of a tool to check if mysql server is accessible since it takes some time to start up.
After you have confirmed the server is running, you can execute the necessary commands. 
TIP: In your entrpoint script you can use environment variables for mysql credentials and pass them to service the same way as to database service

Comment: There are generally two approaches to executing scripts - custom entrypoint or overriding the CMD definition.
I'll update the answer with these examples

Comment: Thank You so much! Yes, I added depends_on section - first is starting database, second one - java app. Custom entrypoint will be the best for me. But when I trying to use it -> entrypoint: - "mysql -h database -P 3306 -u user -p pass < sql_script/create.sql", - without success.

Comment: Are you planning to use this to initialise some data? What's the main purpose for executing the script on container startup? A little more background would be helpful

Comment: I would like to: 1. create database schema. 2. Provide some fake data for testing purpose. 2 .sql files.

Comment: The database schema will be created if you provide the MYSQL_DATABASE environment variable (that will be the name of the schema) 
To import .sql files you can simply mount them under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
(See https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql under section Initializing a fresh instance)
The default entrypoint for this image will automatically detect any .sql .sh and .sql.gz files and execute them in alphabetical order.
I updated the gist with example of how to mount the .sql file

Comment: I did it first time, yes! But, when i used image docker somewhere else, the docker-entrypoint dont see the volume with sql files.

Comment: The image it self does not have those .sql files added to it. If you wish to build a database image that already has all those .sql files in it, then you need to create a custom Dockerfile use mysql as base image and use COPY command to add the .sql files to the needed folder.
Or you simply need to have those dumps available to be mounted...

Comment: I added those files using ADD in dockerfile java app. When I logged to it, there are those files. Now I would like to execute mysql command in entrypoint section in java app, in docker-compose.yml file. It is possible?

Comment: 404 on gist now :-(

Answer (score 1):

1. `vim  /etc/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf`

```
[mysqld]

#skip-networking
```

2. restart the mysql container